# Alerta sobre flags rejeitadas, qual o critério para ser exibido?

Tags: suporte, sinalização

De vez em quando recebo um alerta na janela de sinalizações, porém não estou entendendo qual o critério para ser exibido, uma vez que ele já me foi exibido em diferentes situações.

A mensagem é a em destaque na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso, creio que a origem do alerta foi a rejeição da imagem seguinte, quando sinalizei, o post não se encaixava como resposta, mas foi editado posteriormente antes de ser analisado, o que pode ter motivado a rejeição(não estou discordando da rejeição, foi correta, a edição tornou o post uma resposta).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como sinalizo muito, vejo essa mensagem as vezes, mas a diferença entre o total de uteis sob as rejeitadas é bem grande(esta da imagem é a unica flag rejeitada minha desde 04/09, todas as demais estão como uteis) então imagino que não seja proporcional.

A questão é qual o critério para que esta mensagem surja? Já tive rejeições de flags anteriormente que não geraram essa mensagem.

<sup>*Obs.: ocultei algumas informações das imagens porque o foco da pergunta é o alerta em si, e não o motivo que levou da rejeição.*</sup>

Comment: Não posso afirmar, acredito que seja analisado só as recentes e basta só algumas rejeições mesmo, talvez 2 ou 3. Deve ter um intervalo de tempo onde conte esse número. O sistema nos alerta pra fazer alguma coisa quando um usuário tem apenas 3 perguntas fechadas. (mesmo removidas).

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza, mas pelo que observei o comportamento é o seguinte: Se houver alguma sinalização (flag) sua, mesmo que apenas uma, que tenha sido rejeitada e o sistema acreditar que você ainda não tenha ciência da rejeição, esta mensagem será mostrada.

Como o sistema saberia que você tem ciência da rejeição? Provavelmente ele deve apenas verificar se você visitou ou não a sua página de visualização da lista de sinalizações depois de o moderador ter rejeitado. Esse link da mensagem leva à essa página, e portanto contaria como uma forma de você tomar ciência da rejeição.

Comment: Pode ser mesmo.